# How to create a histogram in Google Sheets with a log scale on x-axis

Tags: google-sheets

I need to create a histogram on Google Sheets, and I need it to have a log scale on the x-axis. This is because there are some random high numbers on my column, most numbers are clustered at the beginning.

The option shows up for the y-axis, but not for the x-axis. I think that when I was trying different options it showed up for a time...???? But now it just disappeared.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try normal chart (bar or line) and building a histogram table manually

Use FREQUENCY() formula for this. This way you can make your own classes the way you like and you can then make whatever chart you like.

[image]

Take a look at my solution - line chart with logarythmic y-scale.
X-scale as I see is unavailable for manipulation, but you can use own values and treat them as text.

Example dataset: 100 random values from 0 to 35.
Classes are powers of 2 (increase by 1/2 with each step)

Here is my example file. See if it helps
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13xVVwhUrMcDj-ec7xpTJv-8cDjlh8zXT46zrqVVLnk0/copy

Comment: This worked! Although the bar chart does not look like the histogram and may be misleading, but it is as good as it gets so THANK YOU!